# TicTacToe Java - check for winner

Tags: java

Here is my code. I am trying to check for the winner. I am only a beginner, so please make it easy. I wanted the board to change sizes. So, I want the check for winner can get use to the size, it will not just check the 9 blocks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class TicTacToe {

    private String[][] board;
    private Scanner console;

    public TicTacToe(String[][] table, Scanner console) {
        this.board = table;
        this.console = console;
    }

    public void makeTable() {
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                board[i][j] = "_";
            }
        }
    }

    public void printTable() {
        System.out.print(" ");
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(" " + i);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + "│");
            for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + "│");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    public void play(Scanner console) {
        int turn = 0;
        String player = "_";
        makeTable();
        printTable();
        while (turn != 9) {
            int x = console.nextInt();
            int y = console.nextInt();

            while (x >= board.length || y >= board[1].length) {
                System.out.println("Out of bounce, try again!!!");
                x = console.nextInt();
                y = console.nextInt();
            }

            while (board[y][x] != "_") {
                System.out.println("Occupied, try again!!!");
                x = console.nextInt();
                y = console.nextInt();
            }

            if (turn % 2 == 0) {
                player = "X";
            } else {
                player = "O";
            }
            board[y][x] = player;
            turn++;
            printTable();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
        String[][] board = new String[3][3];
        TicTacToe ttt = new TicTacToe(board, console);
        ttt.play(console);
    }
}
```

Comment: You have a promising coding style for a beginner. Nice. About the checking, have you tried to do it, and if so, can you include the code of your try?

Comment: [SO is not for code dumps](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88842/discourage-code-dumps). Please describe your problem, steps you've taken to try solving it, etc.

Comment: @DaveNewton I gave him a very very generalized solution. No code, just algo.

Comment: @DaveNewton is that in line with so policy ? =)

Comment: @LittleChild Sure, but my question was more like "why are you talking to me, I didn't say anything to you," but not in a mean way. I just don't know why you're addressing comments to me.

Comment: @DaveNewton Cause you have a high rep and are more likely to know better =)

Comment: @LittleChild A common mistake; I know nothing, ask my boss.

Answer (score 5):

A winning move can only happen when a piece is placed on the board, so you only need to check winning combinations that involve the piece that was just placed on the board.

For example, if the current state of the board is:

```
O X O
X   X
    O
```

And `O` places their piece in the middle of the board:

```
O X O
X O X
    O
```

Then you only need to check the winning combinations that involve this middle piece, namely both diagonals, and the middle column and middle row (4 combinations) out of the total number of winning combinations (8 combinations).

Thus, tracking the last move made is essential to effectively determining if the board is in a winning state.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT

As one person already mentioned, what you're essentially doing is checking to see if the last played move is a winning move. As a result, there really isn't any need to brute force check every row, column, and diagonal systematically to see if there's a winning position or to create some sort of list or table of solutions to check the current board against.

All you really need to do is check the row, column, and diagonal (if the move was on a diagonal) that the move was played on and see if the winning condition is met there.

```
// Takes the row and column coordinates of the last move made
// and checks to see if that move causes the player to win
public boolean isWinner(int row, int col){
    String Player = board[row][col];

    int r = row;
    int c = col;

    boolean onDiagonal = (row == col) || (col == -1 * row + (board.length-1));
    boolean HorizontalWin = true, VerticalWin = true;
    boolean DiagonalWinOne = true; DiagonalWinTwo = true;

    // Check the rows and columns
    for(int n = 0; n < board.length; n++){
        if(!board[r][n].equals(Player))
            HorizontalWin = false;
        if(!board[n][c].equals(Player))
            VerticalWin = false;
    }

    // Only check diagonals if the move is on a diagonal
    if(onDiagonal){
        // Check the diagonals
        for(int n = 0; n < board.length; n++){
            if(!board[n][n].equals(Player))
                DiagonalWinOne = false;
            if(!board[n][-1*n+(board.length-1)].equals(Player))
                DiagonalWinTwo = false;
        }
    }
    else{
        DiagonalWinOne = false;
        DiagonalWinTwo = false;
    }

    boolean hasWon = (HorizontalWin || VerticalWin || DiagonalWinOne || DiagonalWinTwo);

    return hasWon;

}
```

ORIGINAL

A few people have already answered this question, but here's my answer just for the heck of it.

Also, in your play method, you have a while loop to check to make sure that the user doesn't specify a move that is out-of-bounds, but then afterwards you have another while loop check to make sure that the move is in an empty space. You'll still probably want to check to make sure that their new move is also within the boundaries otherwise your loop condition will throw an ArrayOutOfBoundsException.

```
public boolean isWinner(String player){
    // Check for N-in-a-row on the rows and columns
    for(int i = 0; i < board.length; i++){
        boolean verticalWin = true, horizontalWin = true;
        for(int j = 0; j < board.length; j++){
            if(!board[i][j].equals(player)))
                horizontalWin = false;
            if(!board[j][i].equals(player))
                verticalWin = false;
            if(!(horizontalWin || verticalWin))
                break;
        }
        if(horizontalWin || verticalWin)
            return true;
    }

    // If there was a N-in-a-row on the rows or columns
    // the method would have returned by now, so we're
    // going to check the diagonals

    // Check for N-in-a-row on both the diagonals
    boolean diagonalWinOne = true, diagonalWinTwo = true;
    for(int n = 0; n < board.length; n++){
        diagonalWinOne = true;
        diagonalWinTwo = true;
        int row = board.length - 1 - n;
        if(!board[n][n].equals(player))
            diagonalWinOne = false;
        if(!board[row][n].equals(player))
            diagonalWinTwo = false;
        if(!(diagonalOne || diagonalTwo))
            break;
    }

    // If either one of the diagonals has N-in-a-row, then there's a winner
    if(diagonalWinOne || diagonalWinTwo)
        return true;
    // Otherwise, no one has won yet
    else
        return false;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is how I did it when I made tic-tac-toe. I used `String`s

1. Create a 2D array that contains all the possible winning combinations
2. Create two `String` variables, one for each player.
3. Display the board on the table
4. Number each of the blocks from 1 to 9 starting at the top left corner
5. Whenever the either of the user clicks on the board, append the number to the player `String`

Now, here comes the magic part, checking the winner:
 6. For every click on the board, start iterating on the 2d winning combination. Here is how you check if somebody has won:

```
String[][] winningCombo = ... initialization ...
for( int i = 0 ; i < winningCombo.length; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < winningCombo[i].length; j ++){
        char c1 = winningCombo[i][j].charAt(0);
        char c2 = winningCombo[i][j].charAt(1);
        char c3 = winningCombo[i][j].charAt(2);
        if(currentPlayerString.contains(c1) && currentPlayerString.contains(c2) && currentPlayerString.contains(c3)){
            // currentPlayer has won if he has all the 3 positions of a winning combo
        }
    }
}
```

So, if you may consider an alternative approach, you can use that. I used `Swing` for UI and used `GridLayout` to layout the various `JPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

just check rows, cols and both diagonals:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TTT {

private String[][] board;
private Scanner console;
private int size;

public TTT(String[][] table, Scanner console, int size) {
    this.board = table;
    this.console = console;
    this.size = size;
}

public void makeTable() {
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            board[i][j] = "_";
        }
    }
}

public void printTable() {
    System.out.print(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + i);
    }
    System.out.println();
    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(i + "│");
        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(board[i][j] + "│");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public void play(Scanner console) {
    int turn = 0;
    String player = "_";
    makeTable();
    printTable();
    while (turn != 9) {
        int x = console.nextInt();
        int y = console.nextInt();

        while (x >= board.length || y >= board[1].length) {
            System.out.println("Out of bounce, try again!!!");
            x = console.nextInt();
            y = console.nextInt();
        }

        while (board[y][x] != "_") {
            System.out.println("Occupied, try again!!!");
            x = console.nextInt();
            y = console.nextInt();
        }

        if (turn % 2 == 0) {
            player = "X";
        } else {
            player = "O";
        }
        board[y][x] = player;
        turn++;
        printTable();
        if(check()){
            System.out.println("Player "+player+" won!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
public boolean check(){
    //check diagonals
    if(check00ToNN()){
        return true;
    }
    if(check0NToN0()){
        return true;
    }
    for(int i = 0 ; i< size ; i++){

        if(checkCol(i)){
            return true;
        }
        if(checkRow(i)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;

}

public boolean checkRow(int index){

    for(int i = 1 ; i< size ; i++){
        if(board[i-1][index]!=board[i][index]||board[i][index]=="_"){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;


    }
public boolean checkCol(int index){
    for(int i = 1 ; i< size ; i++){
        if(board[index][i-1]!=board[index][i]||board[index][i]=="_"){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;


    }
public boolean check00ToNN(){
    for(int i = 1 ; i< size ; i++){

            if(board[i-1][i-1]!=board[i][i]||board[i][i]=="_"){
                return false;

        }
    }
    return true;
    }

public boolean check0NToN0(){ //diagonal
    for(int i = 1 ; i< size ; i++){

            if(board[i-1][size-i-1]!=board[i][size-i]||board[i][size-i]=="_"){
                return false;
            }

    }
    return true;
    }




public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = 3;
    String[][] board = new String[size][size];
    TTT ttt = new TTT(board, console,size);
    ttt.play(console);
}

}
```

i just look if there is a winner, since i know who had the last turn, i know who it is.

`check()` calls the real checkmethods.

i added `size` since it is scalable.